# PHP DomDocument nodeValue returns Duplicate value

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I am processing very simple html code using php domdocument and xpath. I am getting duplicate value of dom node.

### PHP Code

```
<?php

$html = <<<HTML

    <div id="my-cats">

        <ul class="category_list">

            <li class="item reference">
                <span class="the_score"><b>35</b></span>
                <span class="the_category">Reference / Education</span>
            </li>

            <li class="item computer">
                <span class="the_score"><b>50</b></span>
                <span class="the_category">Computer / Internet</span>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <ul class="category_list">

            <li class="item home">
                <span class="the_score"><b>22</b></span>
                <span class="the_category">Home / Gardening</span>
            </li>

            <li class="item home">
                <span class="the_score"><b>12</b></span>
                <span class="the_category">Home / Repair</span>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);

$cats = $finder->query('//div[@id="my-cats"]//ul[@class="category_list"]//li');

foreach( $cats as $li ){
    echo $li->getAttribute('class') . "\n";
    $value = trim($finder->query('//span[@class="the_score"]', $li)->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $key = trim($finder->query('//span[@class="the_category"]', $li)->item(0)->nodeValue);
    echo "$key : $value\n";
}
```

### Output

```
item reference 
Reference / Education : 35 

item computer 
Reference / Education : 35 

item home 
Reference / Education : 35 

item home 
Reference / Education : 35
```

As you can see I am echoing the classnames which shows the `$li` element I am processing is different. Yet  I get only first value of the dom node.

You can see the problem live in here https://3v4l.org/tjJB5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the inner queries to e.g. `$finder->query('span[@class="the_score"]', $li)` to search `span` children of `$li`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain a bit?

Comment: A path starting with `/` selects down from the document containing the context node so your attempts with `$finder->query('//span[@class="the_score"]', $li)` search the whole document in which the `$li` element is contained. If you want to select child elements then the shortest is the path `span` which is short for `child::span`. Descendants you could find with `descendant::span` or `.//span`.